# laravel sail with intel macbook pro is so slow

Tags: php, laravel, macos, laravel-sail

im using Laravel sail for local development. the problem is each request to takes 2 or 3 seconds to run and this made me so sick. here is my docker-compose.yml which has been built by sail:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${HMR_PORT:-8080}:8080'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html:cached'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
    mysql:
        platform: linux/x86_64
        image: 'mysql:5.7'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql:cached'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh:cached'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}" ]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s

    soketi:
        image: 'quay.io/soketi/soketi:latest-16-alpine'
        environment:
            SOKETI_DEBUG: '1'
            SOKETI_METRICS_SERVER_PORT: '9601'
        ports:
            - '${SOKETI_PORT:-6001}:6001'
            - '${SOKETI_METRICS_SERVER_PORT:-9601}:9601'
        networks:
            - sail


    
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
```

is there a way to make it better?
should i switch to other alternatives like laravel valet or homestead?

Comment: You need to debug what cause this slow. Sail is just docker-compose config.

Comment: @Maksim how to debug it bro, do you have any idea where should i start?